# Google API V3 only one infoWindow open at a time

Tags: javascript, google-api, infowindow

I dont know javascript at all, but I managed to get everything on my map working except this one thing. I'm working on a feature for a forum where members send me their city and state, and I add them to a map. Here's what I have: http://l4ptester.solidwebhost.com/L4p.html
If you click a few map markers youll see that you can have as many infoWindows open at a time as you like, and I dont want that. I only one want infoWindow to be open at a time. So if I click a marker in Florida, and then one in California, the one in Florida will close.

Here's what an entry for a map marker looks like in my code:

```
var InvadermooseLL = new google.maps.LatLng(27.321984,-82.527666);
  var contentString = 
    '<div id="content">'+
    '<center> <strong>Invadermoose</strong> </center>'+
        '<img src="http://www.luxury4play.com/customavatars/avatar16771_3.gif">'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<a href="http://www.luxury4play.com/members/invadermoose.html" '+
        'target="_blank">Invadermoose&#39;s L4P Profile</a>'+
        '<br/><font size="2">(Opens in new tab)</font>'+
        'City: Sarasota'+
        'State: Florida'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

var InvadermooseIW = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var InvadermooseMKR = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: InvadermooseLL,
    map: map,
    title:"Invadermoose"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(InvadermooseMKR, 'click', function() {
    InvadermooseIW.open(map,InvadermooseMKR);
    IrelentlessIW.close(map,IrelentlessMKR);
    Hollywood85IW.close(map,Hollywood85MKR);
    HazeMythIW.close(map,HazeMythMKR);
    jagkidIW.close(map,jagkidMKR);
    DiegoVIW.close(map,DeigoVMKR);
    RaceMindedIW.close(map,RaceMindedMKR);
});
```

I'll explain it a bit. Invadermoose is the user who is getting the map marker, so I'm using that as an ID to keep it organized. so var InvadermooseLL is basically Invadermoose LatLang, InvadermooseMKR is Invadermoose Marker. It just helps me keep it organized.

Now, at the bottom of the script I have all the 'click' functions. It looks to me like it would close the other members markers, but it doesnt work. I read somewhere on Stack overflow that that's the way to do it, but it wont work.

I basically repeat this same code for every user who has a map marker, I just change the Id to their username with my identifying prefixes (LL,MKR,IW), and some of the 'click' functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you think, in the examples you can find the solution is to reuse the `InfoWindow`. This is much cleaner than creating a new one for each user. And if there is only one `InfoWindow`, you can simply update it's position and the the `InfoWindow` closes at the old position and opens again at the new one.

The side effect of this is, that it's impossible to have multiple `InfoWindow` open at the same time, because there actually is only one.